# Storing data in XML string from table

Tags: xml, hana

Is it possible to store data in an XML string in HANA?

Can someone give me an example of how this is done?

Essentially trying to store a substring of a column in a node and connect the result to another table in a select statement. There is not much material on the internet so any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with HANA 2.0 there is very limited support for parsing column values containing XML, see functions XMLEXTRACT and XMLEXTRACTVALUE.

Here is an example with somehow dynamically extracting values from XML-Documents and joining them to some other table.
BUT A WARNING: This example works only if you know exactly how man Items each document contains. I expected getting NULL when accessing Items which do not exist, but instead I receive an error. So, maybe someone can improve on this, or there is just too limited functionality at the moment.

```
drop table "XMLExample";
create column table "XMLExample"
 ("DocID" NVARCHAR(10),
  "Doc" nvarchar(5000) );

 insert into "XMLExample" ("DocID", "Doc") values
  ( '1',
    '<Doc>
    <Item><ID>1</ID><Prod>A</Prod><Quantity>10</Quantity></Item>
    <Item><ID>2</ID><Prod>B</Prod><Quantity>12</Quantity></Item>
    </Doc>'
   );
 insert into "XMLExample" ("DocID", "Doc") values
  ( '2',
    '<Doc>
    <Item><ID>1</ID><Prod>A</Prod><Quantity>1</Quantity></Item>
    <Item><ID>2</ID><Prod>C</Prod><Quantity>3</Quantity></Item>
    </Doc>'
   );

drop table "Products";  
create column table "Products"
("ProdID" NVARCHAR(10),
 "Price" DECIMAL(10,2) );

insert into "Products" ("ProdID", "Price") values ('A', '13.54');
insert into "Products" ("ProdID", "Price") values ('B', '3.00'); 
insert into "Products" ("ProdID", "Price") values ('C', '5.30'); 


select "Items".*, "Price", "Price" * "Quantity" "Total" from
(
    SELECT "DocID", 
      XMLEXTRACTVALUE(
      "XMLExample"."Doc",
      '/Doc/Item[' || "SERIES"."ELEMENT_NUMBER" || ']/ID'
    ) "ItemID",
      XMLEXTRACTVALUE(
      "XMLExample"."Doc",
      '/Doc/Item[' || "SERIES"."ELEMENT_NUMBER" || ']/Prod'
    ) "ProdID",
    XMLEXTRACTVALUE(
      "XMLExample"."Doc",
      '/Doc/Item[' || "SERIES"."ELEMENT_NUMBER" || ']/Quantity'
    ) "Quantity"
     FROM "XMLExample",
      SERIES_GENERATE_INTEGER(1, 0, 2 ) "SERIES" -- replace 2 with your max. number of Items
) "Items"
inner join "Products"
   on "Products"."ProdID" = "Items"."ProdID"      
Order by "DocID", "ItemID"
```

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with HANA 2 XML functions (`XMLEXTRACT` and `XMLEXTRACTVALUE`) are available: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMTn0i0fpT0

Before HANA2 there were no specific XML functions available.

Comment: I see Lars just corrected his answer while I wrote my answer (hard to imagine finding a wrong answer from Lars on SO ;-) ). I will leave my answer because maybe someone is interested in the example.